# How to run two programs, that need different language and don't support Unicode?

Tags: windows-7

I use windows 7. And need run two programs at the same time. Every program need unique value: 'Control panel' - "Languages" - "Additinal" - "Language for programs, that don't use Unicode". This setting's change need computer reboot. Two my programs need two different languages. How do I run them both?

Comment: Did you program either of the two programs? If not, the question is off-topic on StackOverflow (it deals with programming questions). If you did, why are you still using technology from the Windows 95 era? The solution is to join the 21st century and move to Unicode.